# Limit of $\sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n} + \sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm learning calculus, specifically limit of sequences, and need with with the following exercise:

> Find the limit of the following sequences
>
> $$(a) \ \ a_n = \sqrt{2^n + 5^n} \quad \quad (b) \ \ b_n = \sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n} + \sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}.$$

Since I'm having difficulties for $(b)$, I'm going to show my work for $(a)$.

$(a)$ Using the Squeeze Theorem, we observe that

$$\sqrt{2}(2)^{\frac n2} = \sqrt{2^n + 2^n} \leq a_n \leq \sqrt{5^n + 5^n} = \sqrt{2}(5)^{\frac n2}.$$

Obviously

$$\sqrt{2}\lim_{n \to \infty} (2)^{\frac n2} = +\infty = \sqrt{5}\lim_{n \to \infty} (2)^{\frac n2}$$

so for the original sequence we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{2^n + 5^n} = +\infty.$$

---

Is my work/method correct for $(a)$. I wanted to use a similar argument for $(b)$ but I was not able to do it. Is there a clever way to solve $(b)$? I also thought of calculating the limit by multiplying by the conjugate by I think it's not the right method here.

Comment: Is the answer for part (b) equal to 4?

Comment: Write e.g. $3\sqrt[n]{(\frac{2}{3})^n+1}+\sqrt[n]{n}^2\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$. Then you see immediately that you get 4 for $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your work is correct for $a$, although I wouldn't bother bounding it above: the sequence diverges so it suffices to bound it from below by a divergent sequence.

For b,notice that 
$$
\sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}\sim \sqrt[n]{n^2}=n^{2/n}\rightarrow 1
$$
and for large enough $n$ 
$$
\sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n}\sim \sqrt[n]{3^n}
$$
By the property seen here:
[Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a^{n} + b^{n}} = \max(a, b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925186/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnan-bn-maxa-b/1925193#1925193)

Or just prove it by the squeeze theorem
$$
3=\sqrt[n]{3^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{3^n + 3^n}=\sqrt[n]{2*3^n}\rightarrow 3
$$
yielding $b_n\rightarrow 1+3=4$

Comment: Thanks for the tip for $(a)$. I didn't immediately realize it was sufficient to bound the sequence for below.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n} + \sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}=3\sqrt[n]{1 + (\frac{2}{3})^n} + n^{\frac{1}{n}}\sqrt[n]{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}=3\left(1 + (\frac{2}{3})^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}+n^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
we know that limit of 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

see 
$$1 + (\frac{2}{3})^n<n$$
and
$$1 + \frac{1}{n^2}<n$$

so the
$$3\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(1 + (\frac{2}{3})^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n^{\frac{1}{n}}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=3(1)+1(1)=4$$

Answer (score 0):

By taking logs:
$$\log\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}-\log(3)=\frac 1n\log\left(1+\left(\frac 23\right)^n\right)\sim\frac 1n\left(\frac 23\right)^n\to 0$$
Similarly,
$$|\log\sqrt[n]{n^2+1}|\leq\frac 2n\log(n)\to 0.$$