# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a^{n} + b^{n}} = \max(a, b)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

Prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a^{n} + b^{n}} = \max(a, b)$$

I don't have a clue even how to start the proof here. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: factor out one of the two varible, assume it is the bigger one of the two.

Comment: How would you go through this proof if we had $a = 2$ and $b = 3$?  Apply the same principle for arbitrary $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $a\geq b\geq0$ and $a>0$ (if $a=b=0$ the statement is trivial). Write
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a^{n} + b^{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( a\cdot\sqrt[n]{1 + (b/a)^{n}} \right),
$$
with $1\geq (b/a)\geq (b/a)^n$. Then observe that
$$
1\leq\sqrt[n]{1 + (b/a)^{n}}\leq\sqrt[n]{2}\leq 1+1/n,
$$
and conclude that the limit is exactly $a$.

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generality, assume $a \geq b \geq 0$, then we have the following inequality:
$$\sqrt[n]{a^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{a^n + a^n}.$$
Now apply the squeeze principle and the fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1/n} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Whenever $x>y>0$, $x^n>>y^n$, so the larger term dominates inside the radical, and you can "ignore" the smaller term for large enough $n$ and evaluate easily.